# functions defined in terms of their own integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been wondering about problems of this form for a while. For example:
$$f(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$
I would normally approach this by saying:
$$f'(x)=f(x)-f(0)$$
and so:
$$f'(x)-f(x)+f(0)=0$$
is our differential equation. I would now solve this by saying:
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)-f(0)}dx=\int dx$$
giving:
$$\ln|f(x)-f(0)|=x+C_1$$
$$f(x)-f(0)=e^x\Rightarrow f(x)=C_2e^x+f(0)$$
However if we let $x=0$:
$$f(0)=C_2+f(0)\therefore C_2=0$$
Which gives us:
$$f(x)=f(0)$$
However, if we substitute this back into the original problem:
$$f(x)=\int_0^x f(0)dt=xf(0)$$
so they don't agree. Where have I gone wrong, and does a function of this form exist (I initially thought it would just be a function of the form $e^x$ due to its properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ denote an antiderivative of $f$ so $f(x)=F(x)-F(0)$. Differentiating gives $f^\prime(x)=f(x)$, so you made an early mistake.

Answer (score 2):

By the Leibniz rule

$$f'(x)=\frac d{dx}\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=f(x)\,x'-f(0)\,0'=f(x).$$

---

Note that from

$$f'(x)=f(x)$$ the general solution is

$$f(x)=Ce^x,$$ and when we plug it in the integral equation,

$$Ce^x=\int_0^x Ce^x\,dx=C(e^x-1)$$ and the only solution is with $C=0$,

$$f(x)=0.$$